# Blind Eye Pro - What Qualifies?

Tags: nintendo-wii, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I was reading the description of the blind eye pro perk in call of duty modern warfare 3 perk.  It says to destroy someone's streak item.  Does that mean things such as destroying crates, or does that include shooting down spy planes, choppers, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that's a killstreak reward counts, so things like choppers, UAVs, SAM turrets, sentry guns, etc.  If you can destroy it, and the enemy got it because of a killstreak, it counts.

I don't think you can destroy enemy care packages, so that's probably not something that counts towards this.  I believe that shooting down the care package delivery chopper counts, however.

Answer (score 0):

When you destroy a number of enemy killstreaks being used while having Blind Eye equipped, that is when you unlock Blind Eye Pro. This is my Tier One Perk that I use because of it's usefulness of keeping you safe and giving you extra firepower against enemy killstreaks at the same time except for the ones that can be manually controlled, which you can still die from even with Blind Eye Pro, if for example you have Blind Eye Pro equipped and an enemy Reaper is in the air, it can still target you and kill you, it's just harder to spot you because you have no red square around your player character in the enemy killstreak's view.